# RabbitMQ reject message when processing stops with error

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I am using Symfony and the RabbitMQ bundle for an application and encountered the following issue: when a consumer service throws an uncaught exception/error (eg: out of memory), the message is republished and consumed again and again until it gets either a reject or ack signal. I want to change this behavior so that the message is instead discarded if any uncaught exception/error occurs the first time the message is consumed.

Is this possible and, if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to ACK the message. You can do this either by setting the auto-ack flag to true (depends on the language/API/library you are using) or ack the message manually/explicitly. It's completely normal to ack the message that cannot be processed because otherwise like you said `message is republished and consumed again and again`.

If you want you can also [set `requeue` to `false`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html). I don't use PHP for dealing with RabbitMQ so I don't know what is the API equivalent, that is where/how the *nack* is implemented - in that case (not requeing that is) it may be a good idea to configure a [dead letter exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) (quote from the link):

> Messages from a queue can be 'dead-lettered'; that is, republished to
>   another exchange when any of the following events occur:
>
> The message is rejected (basic.reject or basic.nack) with
>   requeue=false,
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example below which should solve your problem. In this case:

- Consumer would work as if nothing has happened.
- Message would be discarded from the queue.

Solution

```
class OrderCreateConsumer implements ConsumerInterface
{
    public function execute(AMQPMessage $message)
    {
        $body = json_decode($message->body, true);

        try {
            // Do whatever you want with $body
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return ConsumerInterface::MSG_REJECT;
        }
    }
}
```

Or full symfony + RabbitMQ example details are here: [The proper ways of handling errors in symfony RabbitMQ consumer](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/4b5a/the-proper-ways-of-handling-errors-in-symfony-rabbitmq-consumer). Looks like options 2,3 and 4 applies to you, which is what you're trying to avoid by the sounds of your question.

Comment: Thanks, BentCoder! I am familiar with the ConsumerInterface constants, however my question is about handling an error that cannot be caught, even if \Throwable, such as "out of memory" or "max execution time exceeded". In these cases, the message gets republished. Can/how could this be changed ? If such an option does exists, it would have to belong to the RabbitMQ configuration, since the PHP script has stopped... I read about the auto-ack flag, which, from my understanding, acknowledges a message once it "taken" for processing, but did not find any way of doing this with RabbitMQ bundle.

Comment: Have you seen this repo for symfony DLE? [The infinite loop problem](https://github.com/cmodijk/RabbitMQBundleBridge/blob/patch-3/doc/dead_letter_exchange.md)

Comment: @medowlock Did you check my answer, the *setting requeue option to false* part ?

Comment: @BentCoder Interesting read, tried it, but doesn't do what I want. This is a solution for when the consumer returns the "reject and requeue" status, not when the consumer is interrupted (sudenly stops).

Comment: @cantSleepNow Yes, but that does not apply in this case, since, as I mentioned above, the consumer does not get the change to return a status.

Answer (score 0):

Closest solution to this I could find until now is to extend the RabbitMq bundle. In the `BaseConsumer` class (namespace `OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq`), there is a method called `setupConsumer` which looks like this:

```
protected function setupConsumer()
{
    if ($this->autoSetupFabric) {
        $this->setupFabric();
    }
    $this->getChannel()->basic_consume($this->queueOptions['name'], $this->getConsumerTag(), false, false, false, false, array($this, 'processMessage'));
}
```

The 4th argument of the `basic_consume` method is called `$no_ack` and is set to `false`. When this parameter is set to `true`, the message is discarded after it is processed regardless of the fact it threw an error or it threw an exception or all went well. So the message gets discarded either way.

Keep in mind thought that when the `$no_ack` parameter is set to `true`, it does not matter what the consumer returns as status, so returning `ConsumerInterface::MSG_REJECT_REQUEUE` would have no effect - the message still gets discarded.

Answer (score 0):

The AMQP protocol provides us with a message [redelivered property](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.redelivered).

I don't know how to do it in RabbitMQBundle (but I completely am sure it is possible). Though I can show you how to do it with Enqueue lib:

```
<?php

use Enqueue\Psr\PsrContext;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrMessage;
use Enqueue\Psr\PsrProcessor;

class FooProcessor implements PsrProcessor
{
    public function process(PsrMessage $message, PsrContext $context)
    {
        if ($message->isRedelivered()) {
            // we already tried to process this message and failed. 

            return self::REJECT;
        }

        // this is the new message we've never seen before. 

        // do the job

        return self::ACK;
    }
}
```

Another way of solving such problems is to delay redelivered messages, again that is possible to do with RabbitMQBundle but you'd have to configure every part manually where enqueue bundle does it. You just have to setup the delay plugin and turn on the config option. More in the [post](https://blog.forma-pro.com/rabbitmq-redelivery-pitfalls-440e0347f4e0)

Try catch is not reliable all the time. You can get an error, such as fatal, which could no be fetched.

Auto ack mode is not good too because you could lose your failed messages without any notices or warning, or ability to recover.